# How to disable going back in my login page in php?

Tags: php, caching

Okay, so here's my problem.
I have a login page. After the user logs in he is redirected to another page.
Now if I press the back button the user is sent back to the login page and now if I press the next page button it will open that user's profile page, without asking for the login information again. Same case is with the logout page. If the user presses back after logging out he can still see his profile.

Login page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="logdes.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
<p id="p">Welcome to E-Voting</p>
<form>
<table width=40% align="center" id="tw">
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="t1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="t2"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" id="td"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="b1">            </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['b1']))
{
$k=$_REQUEST["t1"];
$q=$_REQUEST["t2"];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('project');
$a="select * from login where Username='$k' and password='$q'";
$rs=mysql_query($a);
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0)
{
$_SESSION['username1']=$k;
$_SESSION['password1']=$q;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
if($row['val']==1)
header("location: adminportal.php");
else 
header("location: userportal.php");
}
}
else
{
echo"No record found!";
}
}
?>
```

Profile page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username1']))
{
header("location: voterlogin.php");
}
else
{
$n=$_SESSION['username1'];
$q=$_SESSION['password1'];
echo"Welcome $n";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="logdes.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
<p id="z">Voter's Portal</p>
<form>
<table width=50% align="center" id="tw">
<tr><td><a href="caninfo.php" class="f">List of Election Candidates</a></td>        </tr>
<tr><td><a href="votenow.php" class="f" id="f1">Vote Now</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewresults.php" class="f" id="f2">View Results</a></td></tr>  
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Logout page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$u=$_SESSION['username'];
$p=$_SESSION['password'];
destroy_session_and_data();
echo" You have been logged out.<br>Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to   return to the home page.";
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['username1']))
{
$k=$_SESSION['username1'];
$q=$_SESSION['password1'];
destroy_session_and_data();
echo" You have been logged out.<br>Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to   return to the home page.";
}
function destroy_session_and_data()
{
$_SESSION = array();
setcookie(session_name(), '' , time()-2592000, '/');
session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: what have your tried? What error messages did you get? If no error messages where displayed then please post your php error log. Thank You

Comment: Your login will be storing the login in as a session hence the reason why you wrote session_start() at the top of your script.... You need to clear the session on logout its noting to do with caching..... copying and pasting code you don't understand is a bitch hey?

Comment: I suspect the log out code is not correct.. can you show the code?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to disable cache for this problem. just use session_start on every page at begining of php script and store session when user successfully login with credential and then use that session variable in login page to check session variable is set or not and if session variable is set then you have to redirect to profile page.

If you want exact code for this then share your login page and profile page so i will pull code on there.

Comment: I have provided the login page and profile page and also removed the cache codes. I have used session variables but I think I might have made a mistake some where.

Comment: i check and let you know solution

Comment: Your code are correct for both page so can you tell me what is error there?

Comment: There's no error in the code. But my problem is that after going to the profile page when the user presses back he comes to the login page and then when he presses next he goes back to his profile without entering his details again. And that should not happen. What do I need to do to stop that?

Comment: Where is the log out code? If the user goes back and forth without log out, the behavior is normal.

What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I have added the logout code and linked it to the profile page of user as well as the candidate.

Comment: Can you try to have in the logout page only the following?

<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo " You have been logged out.<br>Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to   return to the home page.";
?>


Then try to test the scenario you mentioned again. Post the results.